# jsPDF. Some mistake in the from_html.js

Tags: javascript, typeerror, jspdf

When I try to export a page in PDF through jsPDF I get the error:

```
TypeError: this.pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight is not a function
```

Note: the page is rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
this.pdf.internal.pageSize.height;
```

if you want to get the height of the page. I haven't heard of getHeight, and if it's a  function you made, give some more code.

Comment: This function is located in the package jsPDF in the file from_html.js.

Comment: Your answer almost helped. Only had to rearrange in all places.